# Is there an inline "OR" operator for arrays?

Tags: php, arrays

Is there any "inline" operator that can make this:

```
$class_map = array(
    'a' => 'long text',
    'b' => 'long text',
    'c' => 'long text',
    'd' => 'other text',
    'e' => 'different text'
);
```

To be something like:

```
$class_map = array(
'a' OR `b` OR `c` => 'long text'
'd' => 'other text',
'e' => 'different text'
);
```

I know about `array_fill_keys()`, but it's not really an "inline" solution, I want to be able to see/edit all my keys and values within the simple `array`.

Comment: ***AFAIK***, no there isn't.

Comment: No only this... "a, b, c"=>

Comment: @devpro that form doesn't work.

Comment: So what you're after is basically a magic piece of syntax to reduce typing when you have multiple entries with the same value?

Comment: There's no magic syntax; but you could define "long text" as a constant and just reference that content when you're building the array

Comment: It will work a,b,c  ...   a-b-c ... remove the spaces.

Comment: @rockyraw This is a cool idea for syntactic improvement to the language.

Comment: @devpro changing `'a'` to either `'a,b'` or `'a, b'` or "a,b", or "a, b" doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such operator specific to array keys. However, there may be other ways to achieve what you may be after more simply by just taking advantage of the very nature of arrays in PHP.

For example...

```
$class_map = [
    'a' => [
        'alias' => ['b','c',],
        'value' => 'long text',
    ],
    'd' => 'other text',
    'e' => 'different text',
];
```

Now your array could be read like this...

```
foreach($class_map as $key => $value) {
    if (is_array($value)) {
        // has aliases...
        foreach($value['alias'] as $v) {
            // do stuff with aliases here
        }
    } else {
        // has no aliases
    }
}
```

For the purposes of searching the aliases you could do something along the lines of...

```
function searchClassMap($className, Array $class_map)
{
    if (isset($class_map[$className])) {
        // if the className already is a key return its value
        return is_array($class_map[$className])
               ? $class_map[$className]['value']
               : $class_map[$className];
    }
    // otherwise search the aliases...
    foreach($class_map as $class => $data) {
        if (!is_array($data) || !isset($data['alias'])) {
            continue;
        }

        if (in_array($className, $data['alias'])) {
            return $data['value'];
        }
    }
}
```